# How to `\textcite` a subentry of an entryset with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Consider the following MWE.  Here I have an `entryset` and would like to use `\texcite` with the middle entry (Weinberg's paper) which should produce `Weinberg [1b]`.  However, instead it prints `Glashow [1]`, the first entry without the subentry, even though I am using the `subentry` option.  How do I get the desired outcome with `\texcite{}`?

(This is with `biber` 2.2 and `biblatex` 3.1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            bibstyle=numeric-comp,
            sorting=none,
            subentry,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a set of references: \cite{stdmodel}.  Now I would like to
refer to just the middle one: \cite{weinberg}.  This works, but
trying to cite them by name fails: \textcite{weinberg} %%% Fails!
(This should read Weinberg~\cite{weinberg}.)

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is simply a limitation of the software. On page 130, the manual says that `When citing a subentry of an entry set, Biblatex provides the data of the parent @set entry to citation commands. This implies that the entrykey field holds the entry key of the parent. The entry key of the child entry being cited is provided in the childentrykey field. This field is only available when citing a subentry of an entry set.`So I think that the *only* information made available by enabling `subentry` is the numerical citation key for the subentry. The author, for example, is not available.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `\textcite` doesn't use `childentrykey` but `\cite` does, of course. But it does suggest that `\textcite` would be useless even if it provided this since the author information would be wrong. (But it seems odd that there is an assumption that the author of the first subentry is author for the set. It seems like this should be, say, undefined or something. That is `Author [1]` is not actually a reference to anything at all.

Comment: As a workaround for my purposes, is there any way to force `\textcite{}` to include a new (possibly duplicate) entry in the references so that the author information is there?

Comment: I'm not sure. Wait for one of the Biblatex gurus to happen by, though. Certainly you can get Biber to do interesting things in terms of mapping and duplication. Just how and just how to hook that up to a citation command.... I'm afraid that is way beyond my ken!

Answer (score 2):

Now, this is really involved ...

The definition of `\textcite` is really complicated in `numeric-comp.cbx`.

The main idea is to wrap the cite command in

```
\iffieldundef{childentrykey}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\begingroup
   \blx@getdata{\thefield{childentrykey}}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}%
   \endgroup}
```

in order to be able to access the information of the "child" entry.

With how `\textcite` is defined that is not really possible, we need to jump through a lot of hoops to get there

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric-comp,
            sorting=none,
            subentry,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\iffieldundef{childentrykey}
     {\global\undef\cbx@saved@childentrykey}
     {\xdef\cbx@saved@childentrykey{\thefield{childentrykey}}}%
   \iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
     {\global\undef\cbx@saved@entrysetcount}
     {\xdef\cbx@saved@entrysetcount{\thefield{entrysetcount}}}%
   \ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifcsundef{cbx@saved@childentrykey}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite}}
    {\blx@ifdata{\cbx@saved@childentrykey}
       {\let\abx@field@entrysetcount\cbx@saved@entrysetcount%
        \begingroup
        \blx@getdata{\cbx@saved@childentrykey}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}%
        \endgroup}
       {}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is a set of references: \cite{stdmodel}.  Now I would like to
refer to just the middle one: \cite{weinberg}.  This works, but
trying to cite them by name fails: \textcite{weinberg} %%% Fails!
(This should read: Weinberg~\cite{weinberg}.)

\textcite{glashow}

\textcite{weinberg}

\textcite{salam}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Citation lists are still a problem, but your basic idea could be incorporated with `\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{childentrykey}{}{\blx@getdata{\thefield{childentrykey}}}`. I have not spent much time thinking about how this approach might be bad, though. Pretty sure subentries are not considered in biber's labelname disambiguation so there's that.

Comment: @Audrey Yes indeed, lists don't work as expected. Unfortunately, the `\AtEveryCitekey`approach has a problem with grouping (?) we still get the info of the overall set, not the childentry. The double structure of `\textcite` seems to take its toll as well, since in the second pass when citations are actually printed I couldn't get `childentr‌​ykey`.

Comment: @Audry: Thanks for looking at this.  There are a few other issues I am encountering with entry sets - especially when multiple sets have the same entry (the subentry lables get mucked up and are no-longer unique).  Are these discussed somewhere?  I would file bug reports or ask additional questions, but I am not quite sure if I am abusing the intended behaviour.  I noticed the [Entry_Sets wiki page](https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/oldwiki/Entry_Sets/) but it seems very out of date.

Comment: @mforbes Biber should warn you about overlapping entry sets. I doubt this scenario is handled well, but if you can find a good motivation for overlap it's something we should look at further. I think you should at least submit an issue to clarify the intended behaviour with `subentry` enabled. The manual only gives a special case.

Comment: @moewe That two-pass structure is my doing. I took some care to ensure the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook worked when I changed `\textcite`, but if you think that is the problem, submit an issue. I just tested on my end - only set overlap seems to make a mess. I'd have to study the code to find other potential cases where the approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @Audrey Two two pass structure seems to do the right thing in all normal cases and `\AtEveryCitekey` works just fine as far as I can tell. It is just that once we get to the second layer of `\textcite`, where the citations are actually printed, the field `childentrykey` doesn't exist any more, so the `\AtEveryCitekey` is useless. When you say you tested at your end, does that mean that `\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldundef{childentrykey}{}{\blx@getdata{\thefield{childentr‌​ykey}}}}` worked for you? Maybe I'm simply doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: @moewe Yes, it works on the example and with citation lists.

Comment: @Audrey I'm very sorry. Your code works wonderfully. I must have made an error copy and pasting because copying your comment from above I get a weird invisible character between the `r` and the `y` in the second `childentrykey`. Please accept my heartfelt apologies for wasting your time. Would you like to add your one-liner as a competing answer or should I incorporate it into mine?